# Finding out when the close button in notepad is clicked

Tags: java

I need to open a notepad at runtime. I do this with the help of ProcessBuilder.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("notepad.exe" , "file.txt");
pb.start();
```

After notepad opens, I type in some stuff and when I click the close button. I want my java program to recognize that and continue with the rest of the program. I know that I could do

```
thread.sleep(*some Long value*)
```

but I think my program will be more efficient if it recognizes when notepad.exe closes.

Comment: Use `p.waitFor`, which will return when the `Process` exits and what exit code it exited with (which might be helpful)

Comment: I'd use a Java-based notepad clone. Here's a simple one: http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~swapneel/1007/Notepad.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this :-

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("notepad.exe" , "file.txt");
Process pro = pb.start();
int val = pro.waitFor();
```

with this `Process pro` will wait for complete execution, also `val` should be `0` for normal termination, according to convention.

**For Getting File Path**:

This `file.txt` will be created at the current directory. SO in order to get the current directory path, you can use :-

`File f = new File(".");
String path = f.getCanonicalPath();`

Comment: Thanks it works! Is there a way by when I can find the file path when I save it from notepad?

Comment: @mashimarro you can get the file path with the updated code.

Comment: You might want to use `new File("")` instead, because `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()` returns a path which ends with `"\."` or `"/."`, so it is a bit of inconvenient if one likes to append something to the path.

Comment: @Tom fixed with `getCanonicalPath()` thanks for notifying :)